# How to preform a segue with mutiple TableView Cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, segue

I have multiple table view cells and I want each of them to preform a specific segue.  I don't know how I would do that

My first cell say first and my second cell name is second.

I have tried dragging from each cell and making a show segue in my mainstoryboard.  But nothing happens when I select the cells.  Do I have to write code or what not sure.  I know I could preform segue with identifier but I don't know what the code for that has to be.  I tried this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: tableView)
```

}

But I can't seem to be able to do that for each of my cells.

All my code is in swift.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have specific segues for specific cells you could do a check on which row is clicked in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and then perform the `segue`. Like this (the `if-statements` are just examples):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: tableView)
    }
    else if (indexPath.row >= 1 && indexPath.row <= 10){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showAnother", sender: tableView)
    }
    else{
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showTheLast", sender: tableView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks works well.  Will give you the check in 4 minutes.